# Which design will be faster on Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I have question about mongoDB.

My system will have Users collection and a user can post on Job Collection. Probably I will want to access user's jobs in future.

So I had two option: First one I can store job id in document of User Collection when user post a job so I can find the job easily with findOne function with given id because I'll store the job id and it'll act like primary key.

Second option I can post the job to Jobs Collection and store user's id as foreign key. I'll retrieve all the jobs with given user id easily. But should find function has to check all documents in collection?

I'm really new to MongoDB so if someone other than me ever faced with this or similar problem can help me? Or maybe you can advice me with better design and solution.

Comment: Do the second approach. And read up on indexes.

Comment: How many jobs per user do you expect? If you don't expect a lot, the best solution is embedding jobs in an array of documents in User.

Comment: @MaximeBeugnet I thought that first but it would be a problem if I want to retrieve all the active jobs for radius.

Comment: @MertSerin That's true. But if it happens only once a day for example you have 1 slow query and 100 thousands of fast queries. The way you access your data should drive your model. Solving your main use cases is the top priority.
You could also store in User an array of ID of jobs or even an array of sub document with a job ID and some useful fields and store all the fields in the job collection (which mean some fields would be duplicated).

Answer (score 0):

MHO...second option would probably be the fastest. However, you may want to think about using ***lookup and aggregation*** to find your information correctly. One would really have to see your entire scheme as it is today. (Which as Sergio said - also read up on use of the index). You seem to be approaching the problem in a SQL manner, (primary key etc.) and it takes time to understand the NoSQL scheme.